# Increase inner padding/margins in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

How to increase/modify the inner margin/padding (the ones maked with red arrows).

The green ones can be increased with `subplots_adjust()`.

Is there a way to change the inner ones (red)?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Change the distance between the source and the observer:

```
ax.dist = 15 # default is 10
```

Comment: Even though this is not exactly the answer to my question (increase the margins) it is a good workaround for some use cases. Therefore +1.

Comment: @wolfrevo did you finally find the proper way to do it ? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @FloW I don't believe there is such a thing as the "proper" way to do exactly this.  You're looking at an inherently 3D construction through a 2D window, the concept of 2D margins is actually not really applicable.