# Adjust whitespace margins on animated Axes3D scatter plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, 3d

I am using matplotlib 1.2.1 and am limited to that version for now. The problem I run into is the crowding of the axis labels and ticks in the bottom of the frame with this rotated plot. I have tried plt.adjust_subplots, I've tried tight_layout, changing the figure size, ax.dist and more but nothing seems to change the appearance as shown in the example image below. This is just one frame but often as the plot rotates, it goes out of frame at the bottom (especially when ticks and labels are bigger). Perhaps my problem is where I place the ax.dist argument?

How can I add a little more whitespace at the bottom of this animated plot? As a bonus, how can I get rid of the confusing double grid lines at the edges? Thank you.

[image]

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']='C:/FFMPEG/bin/ffmpeg.exe'
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def format_3d_ax(ax):
    ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0))
    ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0))
    ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0))
    ax.w_xaxis._axinfo['grid'].update({'linewidth':0.25,'color':'black'})
    ax.w_yaxis._axinfo['grid'].update({'linewidth':0.25,'color':'black'})
    ax.w_zaxis._axinfo['grid'].update({'linewidth':0.25,'color':'black'})

def rotate(i,ax, angles, elev):
    ax.view_init(elev,angles[i])
    plt.draw()
    return ax

def rotate_3d(fig,ax,angles,elev):
    frames=len(angles)
    ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,rotate, fargs=(ax,angles, elev),blit=True,
                                 frames=frames, interval=200)
    return ani

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,7.6))
ax=Axes3D(fig)
ax.view_init(elev=25, azim=0)
format_3d_ax(ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Reasonably sized x label')
ax.set_ylabel('Reasonably sized y label')
ax.set_zlabel('z label')

ax.scatter([1],[1],[1], marker='.', s=80)

ani=rotate_3d(fig,ax,range(0,45),25)

Writer=animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer=Writer(fps=30, bitrate=2000)
ani.save('C:/Temp/test.mp4', writer=writer, dpi=300)

print ('Done') #helps to know when the writer is done.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase inner padding/margins in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678054/increase-inner-padding-margins-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @Ajean Thanks. I had tried adjusting ax.dist as well, but it didn't change the appearance at all in this animation. It may have been where I placed it but I tried different things.